# ansible assert check two strings (or condition) in output

Tags: ansible, assert

How to put or condition for the link "'Nexus 56' in version_output['stdout'][0]['chassis_id']" ? I want to check if 'chassis_id' contains 'Nexus 56' or 'Nexus 60'

```
  - assert:
        that:
          - "'Nexus 56' in version_output['stdout'][0]['chassis_id']"
          - "'n6000' in version_output['stdout'][0]['isan_file_name']"
        fail_msg: "This is not a N5600/N6000 chassis."
        success_msg: "This is a N5600/N6000 chassis."
```

Comment: It is not pointed on the documentation page of the `assert`, indeed, but the `assert` module works with lists like `when` does. [_When you have multiple conditions that all need to be true (that is, a logical `and`), you can specify them as a list_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts). So, a list means `and`, while your needs here are to use an `or`, as you pointed it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

fixed using following:

```
("'Nexus 56' in version_output['stdout'][0]['chassis_id']") or ("'Nexus 60' in version_output['stdout'][0]['chassis_id']")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).